# Show convergence of this series of exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For a result in percolation theory, namely showing that in the subcritical regime we can expect to have finite clusters ($\mathbb{E}_p[|C_0|]<\infty$), I need to show the following:

**Show:** For any integer $d\geq1$ we have that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty ne^{-n^{1/d}}
$$
converges.

**Proofidea:** For $d=1$ we have that by swapping limit and differentiation
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty ne^{-n^{1/d}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty ne^{-n}=e^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{d}{dx}\mid_{x=e^{-1}}x^n=e^{-1}\frac{d}{dx}\mid_{x=e^{-1}}\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{e^{-1}}{(1-e^{-1})^2}<\infty.
$$
Sadly for $d>1$ this procedure doesn't work anymore. I got a hint that I should consider
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty ne^{-n^{1/d}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (ne^{-n^{1/d}/2})e^{-n^{1/d}/2}\leq C_k+\sum_{n=k}^\infty e^{-n^{1/d}/2}
$$
as for $k$ large enough $ne^{-n^{1/d}/2}\leq 1$ for all $n\geq k$ and $C_k<\infty$ some constant. But why is $\sum_{n=k}^\infty e^{-n^{1/d}/2}$ converging, or equivalently $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^{1/d}/2}$?

Comment: How about using the root test for this one?

Comment: @IshraaqParvez I think that the root test cannot be applied, as $\sqrt[n]{e^{-n^{1/d}}}\rightarrow 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The series $u_n = e^{-\beta n^\alpha}$ converges for any $\alpha, \beta \gt 0$. To prove it, remember that

$$e^{-y} \le \frac{1}{y^\gamma}$$ for any $\gamma \gt 0$. Then substitute $y$ with a well suited function of $x$.